# itertools.accumulate() versus functools.reduce()

Tags: python, python-itertools, python-3.3, functools

In Python 3.3, [`itertools.accumulate()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), which normally repeatedly applies an addition operation to the supplied iterable, can now take a function argument as a parameter; this means it now overlaps with [`functools.reduce()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce). With a cursory look, the main differences between the two now would seem to be:

1. `accumulate()` defaults to summing but doesn't let you supply an extra initial condition explicitly while `reduce()` doesn't default to any method but does let you supply an initial condition for use with 1/0-element sequences, and
2. `accumulate()` takes the iterable first while `reduce()` takes the function first.

Are there any other differences between the two? Or is this just a matter of behavior of two functions with initially distinct uses beginning to converge over time?

Comment: accumulate performs a scan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum while reduce performs a fold https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)

Comment: Note that [since Python 3.8, accumulate now also has an optional `initial` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#itertools) so that is no longer a difference between the two.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It seems that `accumulate` keeps the previous results, whereas `reduce` (which is known as fold in other languages) does not necessarily.

e.g. `list(accumulate([1,2,3], operator.add))` would return `[1,3,6]` whereas a plain fold would return `6`

Also (just for fun, don't do this) you can define `accumulate` in terms of `reduce`

```
def accumulate(xs, f):
    return reduce(lambda a, x: a + [f(a[-1], x)], xs[1:], [xs[0]])
```

Comment: I guess you mean `operator.add`. Also, I don't know if the last snippet is really helpful: 1) it returns a list while `itertools.accumulate` returns an iterable, 2) it's terribly inefficient :)

Comment: See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) for a better implementation.

Answer (score 9):

You can see in the documentation what the difference is.  `reduce` returns a *single* result, the sum, product, etc., of the sequence.  `accumulate` returns an iterator over *all* the intermediate results.  Basically, `accumulate` returns an iterator over the results of each step of the `reduce` operation.

Answer (score 7):

`itertools.accumulate`
 is like `reduce` but returns a generator* instead of a value. This generator can give you all the intermediate step values. So basically reduce gives you the last element of what accumulate will give you.

*A generator is like an iterator but can be iterated over only once.