# Calculator - trying to take first number from 'for' and using it as INIT_VALUE

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, reduce, subtraction

I'm trying to take the first number from a list and use it as my initial value. When I started doing subtraction, I realized that you actually don't start at 0 as you do with adding number, but you start with first number written in 'for'.
For example, when you add 0+4+5, then 4+5 is actually the same thing; when subtracting, it's different to do 0-4-5 and 4-5. I'm just starting with Python and programming in general, so I'm wondering if this is even possible.

**My code:**

```
print ("You chose subtraction.")
b = int(input("Enter how many numbers you want to substract."))
c = [int (input( "Number: ")) for _ in range (b)]
result = functools.reduce(operator.sub, c, INIT_VALUE)
print("Your answer is:", result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the first number that was entered by accessing `c[0]` ( or `values[0]`  in my example ), you also only need to subtract the values after this index so you can use `c[1:]` ( or `values[1:]` in my example )

```
import operator
import functools

print("You chose subtraction.")
total_numbers = int(input("Enter how many numbers you want to substract."))
values = [int(input("Number: ")) for _ in range(total_numbers)]
result = functools.reduce(operator.sub, values[1:], values[0])
print("Your answer is:", result)

>> You chose subtraction.
>> Enter how many numbers you want to substract.
> 5
>> Number: 
> 10
>> Number: 
> 1
>> Number: 
> 1
>> Number: 
> 1
>> Number: 
> 1
>> Your answer is: 6
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can do this:

You could get the first number separately:

```
 >>> INIT_VALUE = input('Number: ')
 >>> numbers = [int(input('Number: ')) for _ in range(b - 1)]
 >>> result = reduce(sub, numbers, INIT_VALUE)
```

Alternatively, you could use indexing:

```
 >>> INIT_VALUE = c[0]
 >>> rest = c[1:]
 >>> result = reduce(sub, rest, INIT_VALUE)
```

Or, if you wanted to use a loop instead of reduce:

```
 >>> result = int(input('Number: '))
 >>> for _ in range(b - 1):
 ...     result -= int(input('Number: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `reduce(sub, lst[1:], lst[0])`, but you can also skip the inifializer altogether

```
reduce(sub, lst)
```

If you won't provide it, the first value will be taken

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce

Answer (score 0):

Another option is [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) in Python 3.  This allows you see intermediate calculations.

```
import operator as op
import itertools as it


print("You chose subtraction.")
total_numbers = int(input("Enter how many numbers you want to substract? "))
values = [int(input("Number: ")) for _ in range(total_numbers)]

# You chose subtraction.
# Enter how many numbers you want to substract? 3
# Number: 0
# Number: 5
# Number: 6

results = list(it.accumulate(values, op.sub))
results
# [0, -5, -11]

results[-1]
# -11
```

See also this post comparing [`accumulate` and `reduce`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132545/itertools-accumulate-versus-functools-reduce).

Comment: Oh yes, that's good to know for later, I'll definitely check it out later, but for now I will stick with basics :D